# Extracting (interval) values from multiple dictionaries inside one large list, and combining these with corresponding lists inside another large list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two large lists.

The first one is w_list; one big list of lists with (1) a word (e.g. 'right'), (2) a start id/tag (e.g. '#TWsp10'), and (3) an end id/tag (e.g. '#TWep10'). (The words are from a dialogue between two speakers). Start of w_list:

```
w_list = [['right', '#TWSp10', '#TWEp10'], ['_', '#TWSp11', '#TWEp11'], ['cough', '#TWSp12', '#TWEp12'], ['_', '#TWSp13', '#TWEp13'], ['go', '#TWSp14', '#TWEp14'], [...] , [...]]
```

The second list (t_list) is one large list of dictionaries. The dictionaries consist of (1) 'xml:id' key with corresponding id/tag value (e.g. 'TWsp10', 'TWep10') these values resemble the start and end id's/tags in w_list, meaning the number of dicts in t_list is twice the size of the number of lists in w_list), (2) 'interval' key with a value representing the time the word occured in the dialogue, and (3) a 'since' key which is irrelevant. Start of t_list:

```
t_list = [{'interval': '0', 'xml:id': 'TWSp10', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.2108', 'xml:id': 'TWEp10', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.2108', 'xml:id': 'TWSp11', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.7049', 'xml:id': 'TWEp11', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.7049', 'xml:id': 'TWSp12', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.9223', 'xml:id': 'TWEp12', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.9223', 'xml:id': 'TWSp13', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '1.6568', 'xml:id': 'TWEp13', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '1.6568', 'xml:id': 'TWSp14', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '1.7886', 'xml:id': 'TWEp14', 'since': '#TW0'}, {...} , {...}]
```

This is example output that I would like to create, any hints to get me on the right path/track?:

```
word: 'right' start: 0       end: 0.2108 
word: '_'     start: 0.2108  end: 0.1049
word: 'cough' start: 0.7049  end: 0.9223
''
''
```

Which is 'similar' to:

```
'right' '#TWsp10': 0       '#TWsp10': 0.2108 
'_'     '#TWsp11': 0.2108  '#TWep11': 0.1049
'cough' '#TWsp12': 0.7049  '#TWep12: 0.9223
''
''
```

Creating the word, start and end strings with colon is definitely not a problem. **It's how to extract the interval values from the dicts (in t_list) and combining them with their respective end/start id's/tags from the lists (in w_list).**

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a dictionary of the time intervals, with the tags as keys

`time_dict = {i['xml:id'] : i['interval'] for i in t_list}`

```
time_dict = 
{'TWEp10': '0.2108',
 'TWEp11': '0.7049',
 'TWEp12': '0.9223',
 'TWEp13': '1.6568',
 'TWEp14': '1.7886',
 'TWSp10': '0',
 'TWSp11': '0.2108',
 'TWSp12': '0.7049',
 'TWSp13': '0.9223',
 'TWSp14': '1.6568'}
```

Then simply loop over the word list and retrieve the times

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
for word, start, end in w_list:
    res[word].append({'start':time_dict[start[1:]], 'end': time_dict[end[1:]] })
```

`[1:]` to remove the # from the string

The result:

```
res = 
    {
    "go": [
        {
            "start": "1.6568", 
            "end": "1.7886"
        }
    ], 
    "cough": [
        {
            "start": "0.7049", 
            "end": "0.9223"
        }
    ], 
    "right": [
        {
            "start": "0", 
            "end": "0.2108"
        }
    ], 
    "_": [
        {
            "start": "0.2108", 
            "end": "0.7049"
        }, 
        {
            "start": "0.9223", 
            "end": "1.6568"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit:

Alternative for creating the results from `time_dict`

```
from operator import itemgetter
wlist2 = [(word, float(time_dict[start[1:]]), float(time_dict[end[1:]])) for word, start, end in w_list]
wlist2.sort(key = itemgetter(1))
```

The ten first elements in this list:

```
('right', 0.0, 0.2108)
('_', 0.0, 1.0106)
('_', 0.2108, 0.7049)
('cough', 0.7049, 0.9223)
('_', 0.9223, 1.6568)
('nonvocal', 1.0106, 1.0688)
('_', 1.0688, 2.2074)
('go', 1.6568, 1.7886)
('south', 1.7886, 2.229)
('nonvocal', 2.2074, 2.4019)
```

Comment: @K.Wine Are some of the word occurring several times? Since the dict is using the word as a key, any duplicate word would be lost.. But res could be converted to a list if that's the case

Comment: Actually '-' occured twice in your example data. So i changed the script slightly now. Can you add a pastebin of the complete data, or try to create a new minimal example where the problem is present?

Comment: I can't find any word missing, is there any specific word you know were missing? Did you check again with the last update i did?

Comment: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/anonymous/6cbbcefd49990b007d71 
See this for how i tested it

Comment: See my last edit, it may be better for you, depending on what the use for this is. Printing it out in a nicely formatted table i leave for you to figure out yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
>>> w_list = [['right', '#TWSp10', '#TWEp10'], ['_', '#TWSp11', '#TWEp11'], ['cough', '#TWSp12', '#TWEp12'], ['_', '#TWSp13', '#TWEp13'], ['go', '#TWSp14', '#TWEp14']]
>>> 
>>> t_list = [{'interval': '0', 'xml:id': 'TWSp10', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.2108', 'xml:id': 'TWEp10', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.2108', 'xml:id': 'TWSp11', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.7049', 'xml:id': 'TWEp11', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.7049', 'xml:id': 'TWSp12', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.9223', 'xml:id': 'TWEp12', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '0.9223', 'xml:id': 'TWSp13', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '1.6568', 'xml:id': 'TWEp13', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '1.6568', 'xml:id': 'TWSp14', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'interval': '1.7886', 'xml:id': 'TWEp14', 'since': '#TW0'}]
>>>
>>> for t1 , (t2,t3) in zip(w_list, zip(t_list[::2],t_list[1::2])):
    print 'word: {0[0]:<10} start: {1[interval]:<10} end: {2[interval]:<10}'.format(t1, t2, t3) #for pretty printing 


word: right      start: 0          end: 0.2108    
word: _          start: 0.2108     end: 0.7049    
word: cough      start: 0.7049     end: 0.9223    
word: _          start: 0.9223     end: 1.6568    
word: go         start: 1.6568     end: 1.7886  
>>>
>>> d = {} #save the needed data as a dictionary
>>> for t1 , (t2,t3) in zip(w_list, zip(t_list[::2],t_list[1::2])):
    d[t1[0]] = {'start':t2['interval'], 'end':t3['interval']}
{'go': {'start': '1.6568', 'end': '1.7886'}, 'cough': {'start': '0.7049', 'end': '0.9223'}, 'right': {'start': '0', 'end': '0.2108'}, '_': {'start': '0.9223', 'end': '1.6568'}}
```

**EDIT:**

The problem with the previous approach is what if you are not sure of the same sorting of both list, to get away of this case, sort both lists to the same ordering:

```
>>> import re
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>>
>>> t_sorted = sorted(t_list, key=lambda s:re.findall(r'\d+$',s['xml:id']))
>>> t_sorted = sorted(t_list, key=lambda s:s['xml:id'][-2:]) #if you are sure that the last two are always digits, but I don't recommend it for general cases
>>> t_sorted
[{'xml:id': 'TWSp10', 'interval': '0', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'xml:id': 'TWEp10', 'interval': '0.2108', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'xml:id': 'TWSp11', 'interval': '0.2108', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'xml:id': 'TWEp11', 'interval': '0.7049', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'xml:id': 'TWSp12', 'interval': '0.7049', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'xml:id': 'TWEp12', 'interval': '0.9223', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'xml:id': 'TWSp13', 'interval': '0.9223', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'xml:id': 'TWEp13', 'interval': '1.6568', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'xml:id': 'TWSp14', 'interval': '1.6568', 'since': '#TW0'}, {'xml:id': 'TWEp14', 'interval': '1.7886', 'since': '#TW0'}]
>>>
>>> w_sorted = sorted(w_list, key=itemgetter(1))
>>> w_sorted
[['right', '#TWSp10', '#TWEp10'], ['_', '#TWSp11', '#TWEp11'], ['cough', '#TWSp12', '#TWEp12'], ['_', '#TWSp13', '#TWEp13'], ['go', '#TWSp14', '#TWEp14']]
>>> d = {} #save the needed data as a dictionary
>>> for t1 , (t2,t3) in zip(w_sorted, zip(t_sorted[::2],t_sorted[1::2])):
    d[t1[0]] = {'start':t2['interval'], 'end':t3['interval']}
```

Comment: This would be better than my answer, if the two lists are always correctly ordered.

Comment: @M4rtini...yes..I was going to update my answer to sort the two lists in the same order, first